# Different font heights for each Emacs frame

Tags: frames, fonts

I use multiple monitors with different DPIs so I would like to have all windows in the Emacs frame on a specific monitor with a bigger font height to have the a closer physical appearance to the other monitor. We can assume I won't open the same buffer on separate frames/monitors.

Is this possible?
I'm running brew 24.5 emacs on OSX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can put a function on `after-make-frame-functions` (or perhaps `make-frame-functions`) that tests which display (monitor) is used and adjusts the frame's default font height (size) appropriately.

That function can use function `display-monitor-attributes-list` to determine which display is used. It can then change the size of the frame's font, if appropriate, using function `set-frame-font`.

Comment: Interesting: display-monitor-attributes-list doesn't seem to be able to determine physical dimensions of display port monitor, only hdmi. Can still figure out from the geometry.